# Layout conflicts in android devices

Tags: android, xml, layout, size, screen

I am getting the below error/warning.

```
'Small Screen' is not a best match for any device/locale combination.

[2013-04-02 17:29:31 - X Y ] Displaying it with 'Locale Language ___Region __, sw320dp, w320dp, h426dp, Small Screen, Short screen aspect ratio, Portrait Orientation, Low Density, Finger-based touchscreen, Soft keyboard, No keyboard, Exposed navigation, No navigation, Screen resolution 320x240, API Level 16' which is compatible, but will actually be displayed with another more specific version of the layout.
```

1. cleaning the solution does not fix the problem. The small layouts (such as default 2.7 qvga) continue using Layout sw-320dp for ex.
2. what to do in order to avoid the problem ?